# Hartl's Chapter 7 when pushing to heroku, "pg is not part of the bundle" but it is

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, heroku, rubygems

So I'm going through Hartl's Tutorial on RoR and I'm at the [end of chapter 7](http://ruby.railstutorial.org/chapters/sign-up#sec-deploying_to_production_with_ssl). I'm trying to deploy to heroku. Everything up until the

```
heroku run rake db:migrate
```

step works, but that step gives me the error below. I ran `bundle install` several times and I'm not sure where my problem is. Also I can't access my heroku app online, even if I run `heroku create --stack cedar` and then `git push heroku`. It just gives me an application error when I go to my heroku app URL.

I am currently running Postgres.app and my rails server is not deployed.

Included is my `Gemfile` and `database.yml`. Feel free to look at the code at http://github.com/sambaek

Can someone help out? Thanks!

### Terminal output

```
heroku run rake db:migrate
Running `rake db:migrate` attached to terminal... up, run.1
DEPRECATION WARNING: You have Rails 2.3-style plugins in vendor/plugins! Support for these plugins will be removed in Rails 4.0. Move them out and bundle them in your Gemfile, or fold them in to your app as lib/myplugin/* and config/initializers/myplugin.rb. See the release notes for more on this: http://weblog.rubyonrails.org/2012/1/4/rails-3-2-0-rc2-has-been-released. (called from <top (required)> at /app/Rakefile:7)
DEPRECATION WARNING: You have Rails 2.3-style plugins in vendor/plugins! Support for these plugins will be removed in Rails 4.0. Move them out and bundle them in your Gemfile, or fold them in to your app as lib/myplugin/* and config/initializers/myplugin.rb. See the release notes for more on this: http://weblog.rubyonrails.org/2012/1/4/rails-3-2-0-rc2-has-been-released. (called from <top (required)> at /app/Rakefile:7)
Connecting to database specified by DATABASE_URL
rake aborted!
Please install the postgresql adapter: `gem install activerecord-postgresql-adapter` (pg is not part of the bundle. Add it to Gemfile.)

Tasks: TOP => db:migrate => db:load_config
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

### Gemfile

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails', '3.2.8'
gem 'bootstrap-sass', '2.0.4'
gem 'bcrypt-ruby', '3.0.1'

group :development, :test do
  gem 'rspec-rails', '2.11.0'
  gem 'guard-rspec', '0.5.5'
  gem 'pg'
  # gem 'sqlite3'
  gem 'guard-spork', '0.3.2'
  gem 'spork', '0.9.0'
  gem 'factory_girl_rails', '1.4.0'
end

gem 'annotate', '2.5.0', group: :development

# Gems used only for assets and not required
# in production environments by default.
group :assets do
  gem 'sass-rails',   '3.2.5'
  gem 'coffee-rails', '3.2.2'
  gem 'uglifier', '1.2.3'
end

gem 'jquery-rails', '2.0.2'

group :test do
  gem 'capybara', '1.1.2'
  gem 'rb-fsevent', '0.9.1', :require => false
  gem 'growl', '1.0.3'
end
```

### config/database.yml

```
# postgresql
development:
  host: localhost
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: utf8
  database: sample_app_development
  pool: 5
  username: 
  password: 

test:
  host: localhost
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: utf8
  database: sample_app_test
  pool: 5
  username: 
  password: 

production:
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: utf8
  database: sample_app_production
  pool: 5
  username:
  password:


# sqlite3
# development:
#   adapter: sqlite3
#   database: db/development.sqlite3
#   pool: 5
#   timeout: 5000

# # Warning: The database defined as "test" will be erased and
# # re-generated from your development database when you run "rake".
# # Do not set this db to the same as development or production.
# test:
#   adapter: sqlite3
#   database: db/test.sqlite3
#   pool: 5
#   timeout: 5000

# production:
#   adapter: sqlite3
#   database: db/production.sqlite3
#   pool: 5
#   timeout: 5000
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two problems:

1. Your code on github shows that the `pg` gem is in the `production` group - just take it out  of this group so that it will be included in all environments.
2. The update to your question, which shows your `Gemfile` and `config/database.yml`, puts the `pg` gem inside `test` and `development` environments, where it won't be installed by Heroku

I see your answer below, but you don't need to put the `pg` gem in **any** group if you're using Postgres in all your environments, as it seems you are, based on your `config/database.yml` file.

Comment: Hmm you bring up a good point. I'll do your suggestion. Thanks!

Comment: you write "you don't need to put the pg gem in any group if you're using Postgres in all your environments," <-- why is that?     If the adaptor listed is sqlite3, then is it the case that you'd need gem 'sqlite3' in Gemfile? (rails's default gemfile says adaptor:sqlite3 and that gem 'sqlite3' is required.   I understand that a program can be built to use postgress and then it'll say adaptor:postgresql and you say gem 'pg' isn't then required. Why the difference? (that with adaptor:sqlite3 you need gem 'sqlite3' but with adaptor:postgresql you don't need gem 'pg'?

Answer (score 1):

So it turned out that when I ran `heroku run rake db:migrate` it wasn't installing the `pg` gem because I didn't have a separate `production` group in my `Gemfile`. It works now. Thanks for anyone who put in the time to try to solve the problem!